# How should I classify a typedef with Doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have typedef structs in my C++ code. As of right now they are listed as `\var` typedef. Is there a better way to do this? Below is example of what I have:

```
/*! \var typedef etc
 * \brief A type defined structure for etc 
 *
 * \param x type- Variable declaration for x
 * \param y type- Variable declaration for y
 */
```

I know I shouldn't even be saying `param`. What else is there to use?

Comment: Why the `typedef`? This is C++, not C.

Comment: @Pubby8:  `typedef`s are still used in C++ to improve code readability.  One popular use of `typedef` is creating pointers to functions.  Another is with templates.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I can understand using typedef in that manner, but why `typedef struct` instead of `struct`?

Comment: @Pubby8:  Primarily it is allowed to make porting C code to C++ easier.  The C++ language carried over a lot of C syntax, and this is one of them.  It doesn't interfere with the code nor does it affect the executable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [Doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdtypedef) there is a `\typedef` command. The command behaves the same as the `\var` command.

Answer (score 31):

If you put the comment block in front of the typedef you don't need to use any special command.

```
/** This is the documentation for the following typedef */
typedef MyClass MyTypedef;
```

If you prefer to put it after the typedef use the following:

```
typedef MyClass MyTypedef;
/**< This is the documentation for the preceding typedef */
```

Only when the comment block must be at a different location than the actual typedef, you need to use \typedef.