# Doxygen: C typedef names in description do not become links

Tags: c, struct, hyperlink, doxygen, typedef

I am using Doxygen on C header files, and I have trouble getting the occurrences of typedef names in description text to become links to the respective typedef definition. This works nicely with structures, but not with typedefs.

Example:

```
struct _my_s1;

/** Description for typedef my_s1. */
typedef struct _my_s1 my_s1;

struct _my_s2;

/** Description for typedef my_s2. */
typedef struct _my_s2 my_s2;

/**
 * @brief Structure _my_s1
 */
struct _my_s1 {

    my_s2 * s2t; ///< pointer to my_s2

    struct _my_s2 * s2s; ///< pointer to struct _my_s2

    /**
     * @brief Function f2t
     * @param s2t A pointer to my_s2.
     * @return An integer.
     */
    int (*f2t)(my_s2* s2t);

    /**
     * @brief Function f2s
     * @param s2s A pointer to struct _my_s2.
     * @return An integer.
     */
    int (*f2s)(struct _my_s2* s2s);

};

/**
 * @brief Structure _my_s2
 */
struct _my_s2 {

    int a; ///< integer

};
```

In the output, all occurrences of the typedef name `my_s2` in any description text become just plain text. All occurrences of `struct _my_s2` become links to the structure definition.

I added the description lines for the typedef definitions after reading  [How should I classify a typedef with Doxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933060/how-should-i-classify-a-typedef-with-doxygen) (I was speculating that Doxygen maybe needs to have documentation on something before that something can be the target of a link), but adding the description did not help.

How can I have Doxygen create links to typedefs, like it does for structs?

I am using doxygen 1.8.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I do not get any errors when running doxygen on the example above (there is also @file and @defgroup, not shown here).

Andy

Comment: Have you tried to combine `typedef` and struct definition? Might be it's due to the incomplete type (still wonder why people seperate those actually).

Comment: Just another real good reason to NOT typedef struct definitions